# Test if variable is a date with the correct format

Tags: bash, date

I would like to test if a variable is a date (not a problem), but if the variable have the correct date format (yyyy-MM-dd).

I tried :

```
export DATE_REFRESH=01/01/1900

if ! date -d $DATE_REFRESH "+%Y-%m-%d"; then
    echo "$DATE_REFRESH is not a valid date. Expected format is : yyyy-MM-dd"
fi
```

But it doesn't work.

I can try with this :

```
if [[ $DATE_REFRESH == [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9] ]]
```

But I don't want to have a date to 33/19/2000...

Comment: What are all the date formats you are trying to validate?

Comment: @anubhava Only "yyyy-MM-dd" ;-)

Comment: Hmm but your question is showing value of `01/01/1900` as input

Comment: @anubhava Yes, just for test. The expected result is "01/01/1900 is not a valid date. Expected format is : yyyy-MM-dd"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this snippet:

```
isValidDate() {
   if [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]] && date -d "$1">/dev/null 2>&1; then
      echo "valid"
   else
      echo "invalid"
   fi;
}
```

**Testing:**

```
isValidDate "1900-12-25"
valid

isValidDate "1900-14-25"
invalid

isValidDate "01/01/1900"
invalid
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do both tests because the `date` string can be everything, see the manpage:

> The  --date=STRING  is  a  mostly free format human readable date
>   string such as ...

Use that:

```
if ! [[ "$DATE_REFRESH" =~ ^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}$ ]] \
|| ! date -d $DATE_REFRESH >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "$DATE_REFRESH is not a valid date. Expected format is : yyyy-MM-dd"
fi
```